# How to get rid of exponential numbers in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have converted an image in matlab and Got 1.583e+03, 1.893e+03 as well as negative values -1.545e+03. I want to normalise the values to [0 1].
 please help me how to truncate this exponential number up to 1.583

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, divide by 1000 ?

Comment: Thank you so much. That works well for positive values.What about negative values? It is making them worse

Comment: It really depends on what your are trying to achieve - perhaps you could add more detail to your question?

Comment: Perhaps you just want format long

Comment: Changing your question them down voting people that answered the original isn't cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say " I want to normalise the values to [0 1]. " That is done like this:

```
x = [1.583e+03, 1.893e+03, -1.545e+03]; %data
x = (x - min(x(:)))./(max(x(:))-min(x(:))); %normalized data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1.583e+03, 1.893e+03 -1.545e+03]

x_normalized = x / max(abs(x(:)));

x_1d583 = x_normalized * 1.583
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function

```
function n = ExpToDec( n )

n = n./10.^floor(log10(abs(n)));

end
```